# Remake of factoring/prime factorization calculator

Tags: c++, primes

*Background info on [factoring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization) and [prime factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_factorization)*.

I've remade this program from my [first attempt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24399/simple-and-efficient-code-for-finding-factors-and-prime-factorization), and I'm sure it can still be improved.  My questions:

1. These calculations should only be done with positive integers.  Would something like `template`s help keep this type-safe?  What about throwing an exception?
2. Is this an effective way to use the `typedef`s?  Only the classes need them, so it seems better to qualify them with each class rather than a `namespace`.
3. Can both `calculate()`s be better optimized, considering they perform numerous divisions?
4. I'm not quite liking the call to `calculate()` in both `display()`s, even though there are no data member changes.  Is this still okay?  It doesn't quite make sense to perform the calculations in the constructor, and `calculate()` should still be `private`.

**Factors.h**

```
#ifndef FACTORS_H
#define FACTORS_H

#include <cstdint>
#include <map>

class Factors
{
private:
    typedef std::map<std::uint64_t, std::uint64_t> FactorsList;
    std::uint64_t integer;
    FactorsList calculate() const;

public:
    Factors(std::uint64_t);
    void display() const;
};

#endif
```

**Factors.cpp**

```
#include "Factors.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

Factors::Factors(std::uint64_t i) : integer(i) {}

Factors::FactorsList Factors::calculate() const
{
    float sqrtInt = std::sqrt(static_cast<float>(integer));
    FactorsList factors;

    for (std::uint64_t i = 1; i <= sqrtInt; ++i)
    {
        if (integer % i == 0)
        {
            factors[i] = integer / i;
        }
    }

    return factors;
}

void Factors::display() const
{
    FactorsList factors = calculate();

    for (auto iter = factors.cbegin(); iter != factors.cend(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << iter->first << " x " << iter->second << "\n";
    }
}
```

**Primes.h**

```
#ifndef PRIMES_H
#define PRIMES_H

#include <cstdint>
#include <map>

class Primes
{
private:
    typedef std::map<std::uint64_t, std::uint64_t> PrimesList;
    std::uint64_t integer;
    PrimesList calculate() const;

public:
    Primes(std::uint64_t);
    void display() const;
};

#endif
```

**Primes.cpp**

```
#include "Primes.h"
#include <iostream>

Primes::Primes(std::uint64_t i) : integer(i) {}

Primes::PrimesList Primes::calculate() const
{
    std::uint64_t intCopy = integer;
    std::uint64_t divisor = 2;
    PrimesList primes;

    while (intCopy % divisor == 0)
    {
        intCopy /= divisor;
        primes[divisor]++;
    }

    for (divisor = 3; intCopy > 1; divisor += 2)
    {
        while (intCopy % divisor == 0)
        {
            intCopy /= divisor;
            primes[divisor]++;
        }
    }

    return primes;
}

void Primes::display() const
{
    PrimesList primes = calculate();

    for (auto iter = primes.cbegin(); iter != primes.cend(); ++iter)
    {
        if (iter != primes.cbegin()) std::cout << " x ";
        std::cout << iter->first;
        if (iter->second > 1) std::cout << '^' << iter->second;
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing i can say right off, you could probably roughly double the speed of `Primes::calculate` by checking 2 independently, and then only checking odd numbers.  (Once you've factored out all the 2s, `intCopy` won't be divisible by any even number.)

Comment: @cHao: It works.  Thanks!  You may put that as an answer, along with anything else you find, and I'll vote on it.

Comment: @cHao: I've also just realized that it was already mentioned in my previous question, but oh well.  At least this has been confirmed now.

Comment: @cHao: I'll go ahead and make this change anyway (again, I should've gotten it from the first post).  Feel free to address anything else you may find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use template, if you use template, you won't be able to separate the declarations and definitions of member functions without explicit instantiations, which is exactly what you need. Only the instantiated types will then be allowed. For example;

```
//header file test.h
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

template<typename T>
class Test{
public:
    T doSomething();
};

#endif

//test.cpp
#include"test.h"

//explicit instantiations
template class Test<unsigned char>;
template class Test<unsigned short>;
template class Test<unsigned int>;
template class Test<unsigned long>;
template class Test<unsigned long long>;


template<typename T>
T Test<T>::doSomething(){
    return T();
}

//main.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include"test.h"

int main(){
    std::cout << Test<long>().doSomething(); //linker error, no compilation
    std::cout << Test<unsigned long>().doSomething(); //compile and works well
}
```

Also the use of `typedef` inside the class is not a bad idea. It serves the purpose of keeping the use of the `alias` limited to the class and its members.

Another thing I would like to point out is , since this is a local library, you might as well have a read only file that contains the list of prime numbers attached to the primes library, this will make the prime factorization of very large numbers a lot more faster. For example in the `primes.cpp` file you can add

```
std::ifstream PRIMES;
#define OPEN_PRIMES PRIMES.open("primes");
#define CLOSE_PRIMES PRIMES.close();
```

and you will be able to do

```
std::uint64_t divisor;
OPEN_PRIMES;
for (; intCopy > 1 && PRIMES >> divisor;){
    while (intCopy % divisor == 0){
        intCopy /= divisor;
        primes[divisor]++;
    }
}
CLOSE_PRIMES;
```

Also you can check out how to generate factors from prime factorization.

Comment: So, `Test` will be a new class?  Will `main()` include this along with the other headers, or will `Test` be kept inside of them (and not included in `main()`)?

Comment: @Jamal I don't really understand your first question. Everything depends on how you link.

Comment: I mean, you're defining `Test` as a new class.  I just want to confirm if all the templating will happen in there, while being used by the client code.

Comment: On compilation, the compiler will produce instances of the classes for each template provided and therefore will not take any other instance afterwards. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/by56e477.aspx

Comment: I have the test working.  I just need to figure out how to use this concept with the other classes.

Comment: @Jamal If you google `Template C++`, you'll get many results that can help you have better understanding of templates. Also, consult [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_(C%2B%2B))

Comment: Right.  I'll do that.  This was pretty much not taught in school, so I have to teach myself.

Answer (score 5):

`Factors::calculate()` can be sped up by:

1. performing two integer adds after each iteration to determine loop termination

   - `std::sqrt()`'s overhead, calculations, and casting can be slow
   - `for`-loops shouldn't increment towards a floating-point value
   - incrementing towards an *integer* value is faster *and* proper
   - adding is generally fast and can be done in place of multiplication
2. starting the loop counter at 2 or 3 (if `integer` is even or odd respectively)

   - fewer increments means fewer division operations (division is slow)

This integer add method replaces multiplication as such:

```
0*0 = 0
1*1 = 1 = 0 + 1
2*2 = 4 = 1 + 3
3*3 = 9 = 4 + 5
4*4 = 16 = 9 + 7
// etc.
```

Revised function with explanations:

```
Factors::FactorsList Factors::calculate() const
{
    FactorsList factors;
    std::uint64_t incr = 0;    // will increment by 2 each iteration
    std::uint64_t incrSum = 1; // will accumulate value of 'incr' each iteration

    // if integer is even, i starts at 2
    // if integer is odd, i starts at 3
    std::uint64_t i = (integer % 2 == 0) ? 2 : 3;

    // 'i' is only incremented by 1 for checking each number
    // value of 'incrSum' will determine loop termination
    for (; incrSum <= integer; ++i)
    {
        if (integer % i == 0)
        {
            factors[i] = integer / i;
        }

        incr += 2;
        incrSum += incr;
    }

    return factors;
}
```

Comment: (Non C++ expert talking here) Is one call to `std::sqrt()` really more costly than multiple `i*i` calls? For small number of iterations I would expect this to be true, but at some point I would think that x number of `i*i` calls is less efficient than one `std::sqrt()`

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: I have been told that the function itself is a bit slow.  The main issue with this is that I would need to do casting to work with the function, and I cannot have that in the loop.