# Writing a vector to a file

Tags: c++, c++11, file, vectors

The following function (function template rather) is to take a vector of any type and write it a file using a filestream object.

```
template<class T>
void Vec_WriteFile(const vector<T>& vec, ifstream file, char del = '\n')
{
   for (const T& element : vec) file << element << del;
   file << "\b ";
}
```

This function is very straightforward and simple; however, I'm a student to C++ and would love to learn different ways of doing even the simplest of tasks.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: allow me to change the indentation. that was a mistake i made when i created the post. Not an original code error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the headers your code depends on; don't assume that the user of your code will include them for you:

```
#include <vector>
#include <ostream>  // see note below
```

---

Never require your user to bring names into the current namespace; type names used in your public interface should always be qualified:

```
template<class T>
void Vec_WriteFile(const std::vector<T>& vec, std::ifstream file, char del = '\n')
```

---

Don't attempt to write to an `istream`.  Your output should go to an `ostream` instead.  You could use an `ofstream`, but that's quite specific.  Instead, you should accept a *reference* to any `ostream`; the user can then pass an `ofstream` or `std::cout` or any other output stream:

```
template<class T>
void Vec_WriteFile(const std::vector<T>& vec, std::ostream& file, char del = '\n')
```

---

There's nothing in your code that wouldn't work for a `std::list` equally as well as for a `std::vector`, so you can be more general:

```
template<class Container>
void Vec_WriteFile(const Container& vec, std::ostream& file, char del = '\n')
```

---

Naming: `del` evokes "delete" in my head before I reset and think "delimiter".  It might be better written in full, or perhaps as `sep` for "separator".

---

Layout: at first glance, it's not obvious which code is controlled by the `for` condition, as you have inconsistent indentation.

---

Writing a backspace over the final delimiter isn't the same as not writing the delimiter.  If you want the delimiter between items but not after the final item, the usual way is to track whether the loop is in its first iteration:

```
bool first = true;
for (...) {
    if (first)
        first = false;
    else
        file << del;
    file << element;
}
```

---

Error reporting: instead of just assuming that the writes are all successful, we could report via the return value from the function.  This may help the user remember to deal with errors, which could be overlooked if they have to check the stream state after the call.

---

#### My version:

```
#include <ostream>

template<class Container>
std::ostream& write_container(const Container& c,
                     std::ostream& out,
                     char delimiter = '\n')
{
    bool write_sep = false;
    for (const auto& e: c) {
        if (write_sep)
            out << delimiter;
        else
            write_sep = true;
        out << e;
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That iftstream was a bug on my part. Meant it to be ofstream. I just learned templates two days ago, so I'm still learning how general you can be. Thank you very much, learned more than you can know from your answer.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand you correctly, but wouldn't it be better to avoid this in-loop `if` and just write the first element before the loop? (yes, foreach is far more fancy, but it is a code - not always as beautiful as we wanted it to be)

Comment: what if container is empty? I tend to think the foreach with if checks will accomplish it better

Comment: May want to fix your return type as you are returning from `std::ostream&` to `bool`. No conversion exists.

Comment: @Snowhawk: before `operator bool()` was added in C++11, `operator void*()` served that purpose.  Do you get an error with the above?  If so, which compiler and/or Standard Library implementation?

Comment: @ShmuelH, you can certainly do that; I think it's less clear than the code in the question, but that's subjective of course.  Try it, and see which you prefer.

Comment: @TobySpeight: [tag:c++11] added [`explicit operator bool()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). The use of [`explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) forbids *implicit conversion*, which is what would have taken place because the return type of your function is different from the object type you are returning.  `explicit` has no effect on [*contextual conversions*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions).

Comment: couldn't the delimiter be a template class as well?

Comment: @Ethan [See this review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/13176/infix-iterator-code) as most of the discussion is applicable here.